# Create a custom view showing subviews as defined like UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, interface-builder

When we create a `UITableViewCell` in `InterfaceBuilder`, it shows a content view automatically which you cannot remove. Is there any way that i can create my own custom `UIView` like that which has a content view of its own ? And is automatically shown in interface builder as well. I dont need any subclass of `UITableViewCell` but a subclass of `UIView`

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create a UITableview like view with a content view by creating a model UIView class and putting reported like tag in it .Import this model class to your UIViewController and manually create some delegate method to get number of view added and deleted .But the view should be created programmatically at run time

Answer (score 0):

We need to use UITableView subclass to customise appearance of UITableview cells. We can't do like you asked in objective c.

If you want to customize cells by simply adding additional views, you should add them to the content view so they will be positioned appropriately as the cell transitions into and out of editing mode.

Comment: I dont need a UITableViewCell, I just added UITableViewCell for a reference. I need an altogether different view which has a property contentView the same way UITableViewCell has that property.I dont want to use it in a tableview to be clear.

Comment: Yes you can create a UITableview like view with a content view by creating a model UIView class and putting reported like tag init .Import this model class to your UIViewController and manually create some delegate method to get number of view added and deleted .But the view should be created programmatically at run time

Answer (score 0):

you can create custom tableview cell using nib easily .Please check the link provided below.
https://medium.com/@musawiralishah/creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-nib-xib-files-in-xcode-9bee5824e722

Comment: I am sorry if I was not clear, but I dont need a custom UITableViewCell, I need something similar to it, not subclass of UITableView Cell. I need an altogether different UIView, which has a property ContentView the same its there for a UITableViewCell which is directly shown in InterfaceBuilder when I add it over there, like the same way its shown for a UITableViewCell

Comment: Yes you can create a UITableview like view with a content view  by creating a model UIView class and putting reported like tag init .Import this model class to your UIViewController and manually create some delegate method to get number of view added and deleted .But the view should be created programmatically at run time .

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for this as well but haven't been able to figure it out so far. I don't think IB supports it at the moment. I did, however, based on @A_curious_developer' answer find a workaround that works well for me.

**TL;DR**: The trick is to use the contentView's tag to reference it in code, then use Auto Layout to set the appropriate constraints depending on your needs.

Here's an example:

First, I created my custom view. It has a "bubble/tooltip" at the bottom and an empty view (selected) at the top.

[image]

Then, I used this custom view in my view controller and added a subview to it to act as the contentView (white background, selected). I also gave it a tag (12345).

[image]

Finally, I look for this tag in my custom view's `awakeFromNib` and set the appropriate constraints.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    if let view = viewWithTag(12345) {
        theContent = view

        // set constraints here...
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!